# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my function:

```
  getIndicators(){
    const {pages} = this.state
    var indicators = null
    for(var i = 0 ; i < pages.length ; ++i){
      if(pages[i].active)
        indicators += <View style={styles.activeCircle} />
      else
        indicators += <View style={styles.inActiveCircle} />  
    }

    return indicators;
  }
```

inside my `return` of `render` function:

```
 <View style={{width:'70%',height:'100%',justifyContent:'center',flexDirection:'row',alignSelf:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
  {this.getIndicators()}
 </View>
```

but I got this error message:

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to parent without a
>   measure.

I must use this function. without it, I have to write hard-code.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `indicators` as an empty array instead of `null`?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are concatenating the views together. They need to be added to an array. Also if you loop over items the will need to have a unique key property, which I have added in the updated `getIndicators` function below.

If you update your `getIndicators` function to the following it should work

```
getIndicators = () => {
  const {pages} = this.state
  var indicators = []
  for(var i = 0 ; i < pages.length ; ++i){
    if(pages[i].active)
      indicators.push(<View key={i} style={styles.activeCircle} />)
    else
      indicators.push(<View key={i} style={styles.inActiveCircle} />)  
  }
  return indicators;
}
```